# How to get rid of "cancels Place Item in Tomb: Item inaccessible"?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I was ambushed by goblins, and some merchants hanging around were killed. Then, I defined a burrow and ordered the dwarves inside. But now, I'm getting spammed by "Urist McUrist cancels Place Item in Tomb: Item inaccessible". I suppose they're trying to bury the dead merchants outside of their burrow. How can I get rid of that? Killing the crossbowmen isn't really an option as I have no military.

Comment: You are not playing Minecraft. What game are you playing?

Comment: Oops, sorry. It's Dwarf Fortress.

Comment: Odd, the related questions still show minecraft questions for me.

Comment: @Ids - Hm, same here. Those must be set at question creation time. Anna, I have this problem all the time, with the few dwarves that get caught outside and killed before I manage to lock down the fortress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to activate area forbidding and draw a box around the dead merchants. This will forbid your dwarves from attempting jobs concerning the corpses, and will prevent the message spam.